# Volley as Dependency

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, android-volley

I just looked into an older projects of mine. It used volley in gradle:

compile project (":volley")

I used it as submodule, but i want to get rid of it.

As Volley is maintained by google, i found after some research some official dependency [1]. The Version Nr is 1.0.0

Does anyone can tell me which version of Volley belongs this to ?
There are quite a few [2]

[1] https://bintray.com/android/android-utils/com.android.volley.volley/view#

[2] https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+refs

Answer (score 0):

I think Google finally published their code "normally" and even `mcxiaoke` who was the guy always took the repo from deprecated his own repo:

> Please note, this project is deprecated and no longer being maintained, please use official version from jCenter.

So now, just:

`compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'`